# PHP Mailer Class

Tags: php, email

I use the PHP Mailer Class along with the SMTP extension to send e-mail.
The problem is that the php script sends emails only to YAHOO or GMAIL addresses but when I try to send to blabla@neobee.net, I never receive the email.

There are no error messaged when I send to `blabla@neobee.net`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things to be checked before you can send mail from a server.

Many recipient mail servers need something called as spf record to be set at the sender's domain:
www.openspf.org/Introduction

I think , if you are not sending more than 100 mails a day , a better approach would be to use smtp mailer along with google mail
[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

So in that way you need not mess or worry about spf or DKIM .. 
Its a simple solution but your email would have `something@gmail.com` that wouldn't be so professional , so if you are looking for professional solution then you need to look for setting up spf records and DKIM for your domain

Comment: Now I added to the email things like AddReplyTo, From, FromName, Subject and it works now!

Comment: accept the answer if it solves your problem and vote up if you feel answer is good.